# Disabling pytest plugin works locally, doesn't work on CI

Tags: python, plugins, pytest

I have a pytest setup with the following config file I use for integration tests:

```
[pytest]
addopts = -p no:python -p no:random-order --tb=short
junit_suite_name = Integration
filterwarnings =
    ignore::DeprecationWarning
```

The aim is to not load the `random-order` plugin. When running locally, I get this as the output:

```
$ pytest -c pytest-integration.ini --junitxml=integration-tests.xml tests/integration/

======================= test session starts ===========================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.4, pytest-3.7.2, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.0
rootdir: /Users/ringods/Projects/customer/project/tests/integration, 
inifile: pytest-integration.ini
plugins: cov-2.6.0, mamba-1.0.0
collected 629 items
```

As expected, no trace of the `random-order` plugin. I pushed my changes to our build server (Jenkins), and this is the output from Jenkins:

```
+ pytest -c pytest-integration.ini --junitxml=integration-tests.xml tests/integration/

===================== test session starts ========================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.3, pytest-3.7.2, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.0
Test order randomisation NOT enabled. Enable with --random-order or -- random-order-bucket=<bucket_type>
rootdir: /home/centos/workspace/test-reporting-L2CS5UFPVK3I5UNI6BJIMJPWQQMDOV465LKDS2BSKJ5UXDZGAI6Q/tests/integration, inifile: pytest-integration.ini
plugins: random-order-1.0.4, cov-2.6.0, mamba-1.0.0
collected 629 items
```

I can not seem to find why the `random-order` plugin is still loaded. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that config file which you use locally is same as in Jenkins.
Please check if you have pushed changes in config file as well.

Comment: All my local changes were committed to Git and pushed. The posted CI output came from the build of that commit.